# How can one access perfmon (windows server 2008) raw collected data from an ASP.NET web application?

Tags: asp.net, perfmon

In an ASP.NET web application, how can I access the raw data collected from perfmon in windows server 2008?

Comment: the same way you would access any other file....

Comment: could you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [PerformanceCounter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) in System.Diagnostics is what you might be looking for.